# Java 11 hashmap deadlock

Tags: java, multithreading, hashmap

Here are a few lines of code which I wrote to test hashmap's performance in a multi-threading environment. I know that hashmap may cause deadlock with java8, but I am using java 11. It does not throw any exception, and never stop. Can someone help me to understand why? Thank you.

Response is a very simple entity class.

[dealock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OFmX.png)

[Response.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdfN4.png)

Comment: Please include the code into the question; don't supply it through external links. Questions should be self-contained.

Comment: HashMap is not thread safe, why do you expect your program to run correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java 11 implementation has not introduced thread-safe implementation of `java.util.HashMap`.

In the JDK documentation, it is clearly stated that access to `Hashmap` is NOT synchronized, so the behavior in a multithreaded application is unpredictable, and deadlock situation is indeed a possible side effect.

In addition, it is also said that if you want to have synchronized access, you MUST provide synchronization policy by using static method `Collections.synchronizedMap`, this is the piece of code to realize that:

```
Map m = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap(...));
```

Moreover, bear in mind that also the iterator provided implicitly or explicitly over the keyset or valueset is "fail-fast", which means that it throws immediately a `ConcurrentModificationException` when iterating through them and the map gets modified without using specific `add` or `remove` methods of the iterator itself.

If you are looking for better performances and, in particular, if you want to avoid any race condition, you can alternatively use `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap`, which guarantees not to throw any `ConcurrentModificationException`.

In this case as well you can simply wrap your map with an instance of the concurrent one, so given `K` and `V` the types of the key and value:

```
Map<K,V> m = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(myHashMap);
```